# ceph-deploy osd create --data /dev/vdb fails

Tags: ceph

From my ceph (mimic release) administrative node I ran

```
ceph-deploy osd create --data /dev/vdb ceph0
```

against a bare metal ceph node and it worked without error.

Now I run the same command against a virtual ceph node (with an unpartitioned qcow2 disk attached) and the command times out. I see no evidence of any progress having been made on this virtual machine. The target VM sees its vdb disk and virsh shows the disk as being properly attached.

The data disk on the bare metal machine is 500GB while the virtual disk on the virtual machine node is only 30GB. Could this massive size difference be the problem? Should I try using a raw .img disk instead of qcow2?

Thnx.

Comment: The vm's ceph data disk was created with
`fallocate -l 20480M /home/libvirt/images/ceph1-store.qcow2`

Comment: Should have used, 
`qemu-img create -f qcow2 -o preallocation=full  /home/libvirt/images/ceph1-store.qcow2 30G`

Comment: The server with the physical disk is CentOS 7 while all the virtuals are Ubuntu Bionic.

Comment: Latest error: 
`auth: unable to find a keyring on /etc/ceph/ceph.client.admin.keyring,/etc/ceph/ceph.keyring,/etc/ceph/keyring,/etc/ceph/keyring.bin,: (2) No such file or directory`
Is it talking about the remote system or my cephadmin host?

Comment: did you run  `ceph-deploy disk zap ceph0 /dev/vdb` first before running your create command?